# Breadth first search stuck in infinite loop

Tags: c++, graph-theory, breadth-first-search, graph-traversal

I am trying to implement breadth first search algorithm but due to some reasons it is getting stuck in infinite loop.

I have tried debugging it by outputting various values but still no success.

My Bfs Code

```
    int s=0;
    bool vis[n];
    int dist[n];

    for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
        vis[i]=false;
        dist[i]=INT_MAX;
    }

    dist[s]=0;
    vis[s]=true;
    q_push(s);



    while(!q_isEmpty()){
        int u = queu[0];
        for(int v=0;v<n;v++){
            if(adjMat[u][v]==1){
                if(vis[v]==false){
                    vis[v] == true;
                    dist[v]=dist[u]+1;
                    q_push(v);
                    cout<<v;
                }
            }
        }

        q_pop();


    }
```

My queue is globally declared its code

```
vector <int> queu;

void q_push(int d){
    queu.insert(queu.end(),d);

}

void q_pop(){
    queu.erase(queu.begin());
}

bool q_isEmpty(){
    return queu.empty();
}
```

I take adjacency matrix as input its code.

```
int n;
cin>>n;
for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
    for(int j=0;j<n;j++){
        int temp;
        cin>>temp;
        adjMat[i][j]=temp;
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the variable `n` assigned?

Comment: Did you know there is a [std::queue](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/queue)?  Also please post a [mcve].

Comment: @c_sagan Number of nodes

Comment: vis[v] == true;

Comment: @Imretardedbut -- `bool vis[n];` -- If `n` is not a constant, then that code is not valid C++.  Use `std::vector` instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change this:

```
vis[v] == true;
```

to this:

```
vis[v] = true;
```

since you want to mark the adjacent node `v` as visited, by assigning it the value true - you mistakenly used the comparison operator instead of the assignment operator, so you keep and keep visiting nodes that you already traversed, again and again, going into an infinite loop..

PS: Not the cause of the infinite loop, but as @PaulMcKenzie commented, you could/should use an [`std::queue`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/queue/queue/).

Comment: Thanks for the help. I was trying to implement everything from scratch for better understanding

Comment: No problem @Imretardedbut, practice is good! :) If my answer solved your issue, you can accept it if you want.